# Removing one item from array results in removing all items at first?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a simple to-do list app with angular and cannot seem to figure out this strange bug. When the page loads initially, if I add tasks to my to-do list, then try to delete one the whole list disappears. However, if I don't refresh and add more task, they will delete individually afterwards. Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Factory:

```
//Save user in local storage
AccountFactory.saveUser = function (user) {
    var users = getUsers();
    var index = this.getUser(user.email, 'index');
    users[index] = user;
    localStorage.setItem('Users', JSON.stringify(users));
    return { status: 200, message: 'User saved', data: user };
};

AccountFactory.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    return { status: 200, message: 'Current user set', data: user };
};

//Delete Task
AccountFactory.removeTask = function (user, task) {
    var index = user.tasks.indexOf(task);
    user.tasks.splice(index, 1);
    return this.saveUser(user);
}

//Get all users function
function getUsers() {
    var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Users')) || [];
    return users;
}

//Get user function
AccountFactory.getUser = function (email, type) {
    var users = getUsers();
    var account,
        index;
    for (var i = 0, user; user = users[i]; i++) {
        if (user.email.toLowerCase() === email.toLowerCase()) {
            account = user;
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (type === 'account') return account;
    if (type === 'index') return index;
};
```

Controller:

```
function saveUser(user) {
    var response = AccountFactory.saveUser(user);
    if (response.status === 200) {
        var newUser = new User(response.data);
        AccountFactory.setCurrentUser(user);
        $scope.user = user;
        console.log(response.message);
    }
}

$scope.removeTask = function (task) {
    var response = AccountFactory.removeTask($scope.user, task);
    saveUser(user);
}
```

Comment: show the implementation in the `saveUser` function

Comment: Right. Forgot to add that

Comment: In your `factory` you're doing this: `return this.saveUser(user);`.. where is this function?

Comment: I added that function too, as well getUser() and getUsers() if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you calling `saveUser` from within the factory when you delete a task and after that you call it again from your controller. You are doing the exact same operation.

Comment: Good point. I suppose I don't need to save the user in both. I'm still a noob with angular, and JavaScript for that matter. However, when I remove the function from either that doesn't help with the issue I'm having.